# Ruby, adding methods to a Module, Class or Object

Tags: ruby

I noticed something odd while I was adding methods to `Kernel` to make them available globally. It's interesting, and I'm looking for some documentation or good explanation.

Let's look at the code:

**file: ./demo.rb**

```
# example 1

module Kernel
  def foo
    puts "I'm defined inside the module!"
  end
end


# example 2

module Bar
  def bar
    puts "I'm included! (bar)"
  end
end

Kernel.send :include, Bar


# example 3

module Baz
  def baz
    puts "I'm included! (baz)"
  end
end

module Kernel
  include Baz
end
```

**Then, in bash and IRB**

```
$ irb -r ./demo.rb
> foo
# I'm defined inside the module!
> bar
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for main:Object
> baz
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object
>
> self.class.ancestors
# => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
>
> include Kernel
>
> self.class.ancestors
# => [Object, Kernel, Baz, Bar, BasicObject]
>
> foo
# I'm defined inside the module!
> bar
# I'm included! (bar)
> baz
# I'm included! (baz)
```

`foo` works as expected, and is available for all objects that include `Kernel`. `bar` and `baz`, on the other hand, are not immediately available.
I imagine it's because the *evaluation context* of IRB (an `Object`) already includes `Kernel`, and including a module A inside a module B will not "reload" all previous inclusions of B.
Ok, it makes perfect sense, and in fact re-including `Kernel` will add the other two methods.

Then, my questions are:

1. Why does *opening* `Kernel` work? (example 1)
2. if *opening* the module is treated differently, why isn't the 3rd example working as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you call `foo.bar` in Ruby? Something like this:

```
foo.class.ancestors.each do |klass|
  if klass.public_instance_methods.include? :bar
    return klass.instance_method(:bar).bind(foo).call
  end
end
raise NameError
```

i.e. Ruby searches through the ancestors to find a matching instance method.

And what happens when you call `A.include B` in Ruby? Something like this:

```
B.ancestors.each do |mod|
  A.ancestors << mod unless A.ancestors.include? mod
end
```

`B` and all of its ancestors become ancestors of `A`. These two behaviors explain everything:

1. Opening `Kernel` works because it's included in `Object` and is thus an ancestor of every object, meaning its methods (including new ones) can be searched whenever you call a method on any object.
2. Opening a module isn't treated differently. Your second and third examples are effectively the same. They both don't work because `Kernel`'s ancestors are only searched when it is included, which was before you added new ancestors to it.

Comment: Thanks. Clear, and it addresses my doubt exactly. Do you know of any good resource on this kind of behaviour? Or should I _use the source, Luke_?

Comment: [Programming Ruby](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) explains some of this stuff, but I did have to dig through the source to figure out how `include` deals with the module's ancestors.